# how to reuse symfony route

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I want to reuse a route in symfony as I used in Slim framework.
for example: in Slim I could define groups and then I would put the actions inside the group:

```
$app->group("example",..{
  $app->get("/staff"...);
  $app->get("test");

  $aap->group("books",..{
    $app->get("/"..);
    $app->delete("/{id}")
  })
});
```

And to access to the action test the url would be like: `"domain/example/test"`, and to access staff: `"domain/example/staff"`;
and to access book would be like: `"domain/example/book/"`;

can I do this in symfony without having to go to every controller and put it manually.

Comment: how do you define your routes atm?

Comment: My routes are defined in the actions annotations...

Answer (score 1):

The [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-prefix) provide an example on how defines a prefix for all action routes:

```
/**
 * @Route("/example")
 */
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/staff")
     */
    public function staffAction()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * @Route("/example/books")
 */
class BookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}")
     * @Method({"DELETE"})
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, the situation is: imagine that I have 10 Controllers, and I want to change the example route, I'll have to go to all of them, one by one, to change the example to other route... I want a place where I can define the common route and tell which Controller will use the prefix